# Spark map/Filter throws java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before newline: 2147483648

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am having a simple file of size 7 GB in which each line containing two column separated by |.I have created RDD from this file but when i use map or filter transformation on this RDD i gets too many byte exception.

below is sample data from my file .

116010100000000007|33448

116010100000000014|13520

116010100000000021|97132

116010100000000049|82891

116010100000000049|82890

116010100000000056|93014

116010100000000063|43434

116010100000000063|43434

here is the code

```
val input = sparkContext.textFile("hdfsfilePath");

input.filter(x=>x.split("|")(1).toInt > 15000).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://output file path")
```

Below is the Exception i am getting .

```
java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before newline: 2147483648
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:249)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:136)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you presented the actual code + the stack trace you get.

Comment: Please edit the question with the code above.

Comment: where is the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with my scala code while splitting line with pipe delimiter ,i have changed the code and now it is working.
below is changed code .

```
          val input = sparkContext.textFile("hdfsfilePath");

          input.filter(x=>x.split('|')(1).toInt > 15000).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://output file path")
```

instead of "|" i neeed to use either '|' or "\\|" in split method.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently.

For me, this was not a memory issue or scala code issue.

It turned out to be an incomplete/malformed CSV, i.e. the last row of the CSV file was cut short.

To resolve this I manually removed the last line using

```
sed -i '$d' /fileName
```

But if this a common issue for you, it may be better to use databricks spark-csv package:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

It includes: DROPMALFORMED: drops lines which have fewer or more tokens than expected or tokens which do not match the schema. Which is likely to be useful in my case.